# Class no Angular 2

Tags: classes, angular

Essa é minha classe no angular 2

```
export class LinhaModel {
    _id: string;

    Cidade: {
        id: string;
        CidadeNome: string;
    }

    Operador: {
        id: string,
        OperadorNome: string,
    }

    DiaOperacional: {
        id: string,
        DiaOperacionalNome: string,
    }

    CategoriaLinha: {
        id: string,
        CategoriaLinhaNome: string,
    }

    Acessibilidade: boolean

    Tarifa: number

    NomeLinha: string

    CodigoLinha: string

    ViagemA: {
        Origem: string

        Destino: string

        Horarios: any[]

        Vias: [
            {
                ViaNome: string
                ViaHorarios: any[]
            }
        ]
    }


    ViagemB: {
        Origem: string

        Destino: string

        Horarios: any

        Vias: [
            {
                ViaNome: string
                ViaHorarios: any
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

faço a instancia da minha model assim

private model: LinhaModel = new LinhaModel();

e quando tento acessar minha propriedade com this.model.ViagemA.Origem não é aceito! alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a propriedade ViagemA não está pronta para uso (ViagemA = undefined), pois nenhuma instância foi definida nela. Antes de usá-la, você precisa atribuir um objeto que siga o contrato/formato estabelecido, ou seja, um objeto que tenha os membros: Origem (string), Destino (string), Horarios (array), Vias (array de um tipo X).

A solução, para não receber erros de undefined, seria criar um construtor na classe LinhaModel para inicializar a propriedade ViagemA. Por exemplo:

```
export class LinhaModel {

    constructor()
    {
        this.ViagemA = {};
    }

   ViagemA: {
    Origem: string

    Destino: string

    Horarios: any[]

    Vias: [
        {
            ViaNome: string
            ViaHorarios: any[]
        }
    ]
}


}
```